# How to Share Windows 8 files with Ubuntu Server 12.10

Tags: windows-8, samba, ubuntu-server, cifs

On my network I have a Windows 8 laptop and a Ubuntu Server running 12.10. I can connect to a Ubuntu file share from my Windows 8 laptop with out any issues.

Question: How would I connect & mount a Windows file share from my Ubuntu Server?

This has to be possible seeing I can connect to a Ubuntu Share from Windows 8.

Comment: I did make a directory in /mnt as well as created a new Windows user called smbuser. Added new user to share. Used this: sudo mount -t cifs //"HOSTNAME"/UbuntuTest /mnt/remote -o username=smbuser   Error "could not resolve address for host"  Used IP instead. Next asked for Password. Put Windows user password in. Error "host is down:

Answer (score 3):

Ubuntu and Gnome make it easy to access files on a Windows network share.

Open the *Places Menu*, then click on *Network*. You will see a Windows network icon. Double-click to open it. The next window shows all the domains/workgroups found on your network. Inside each domain/workgroup, you will see all the computers on the domain/workgroup with sharing enabled. Double-click on a computer icon to access its shares and files.

If you want to do it from the command line only:

```
sudo apt-get install samba smbclient
```

To mount Windows filesystems using SMB, you will also need smbfs. Enter the command:

```
sudo apt-get install smbfs
```

Connecting from the command line is similar to an FTP connection.

List public SMB shares with

```
smbclient -L //server -U user
```

Connect to a SMB share with

```
smbclient //server/share -U user
```

Enter your user password.
You can connect directly with

```
smbclient //server/share -U user%password
```

but your password will show on the screen (less secure).

Once connected, you will get a prompt that looks like this:

```
smb: \>
```

Type "help", without quotes, at the prompt for a list of available commands.

If you want to mount the Windows share, you need

```
sudo apt-get install smbfs
```

then something like:

```
mkdir ~/mnt
sudo mount -t cifs //myserver_ip_address/myshare ~/mnt -o username=samb_user,noexec
```

Comment: I will try the commands. I do not have GNOME desktop environment on the Ubuntu Server.

Comment: For some ODD reason I had assumed that Ubuntu Server already came with a samba client. Might of found my problem.

Comment: Thanks Bubba! However When i try to list the shares on my Windows laptop using smbclient -L //192.168.1.72 -U smbuser   , I get 
session request to 192.168.1.72 failed (Called name not present)
session request to 192 failed (Called name not present) session request to *SMBSERVER failed (Called name not present) I just created that windows user and added it to the Windows share because the username I'm logged in with right now is connected to a domain. I can ping my Windows Laptop.

Comment: you don't appear to have a share name after the ipaddress?

Answer (score 0):

The samba service allows linux machines to connect to windows machines.

Here's one of a ton of articles on the subject:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/29167/3-easy-ways-to-connect-to-windows-shared-folders-from-linux/

Comment: These resolutions use nautilus which is a gui based tool for Desktop version of Ubuntu not Server version. I do not have x-windows interface such a GNOME on the Ubuntu Server.

Comment: smbclient and sbm mounts work on the command line as well.  Google is your friend.  There are about 100000000000000000 resources.   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountWindowsSharesPermanently

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend that you [use Autofs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Autofs) to mount your Windows shares.  This has many advantages over smbclient or adding cifs mounts to your fstab.  Autofs is tolerant of reboots, disconnects when idle, reconnects on demand automatically, and is completely transparent at the user level.  Give it a shot.

Here's an example setup.

**/etc/auto.master**

```
# bunch of comments

/cifs   auto.cifs  --ghost

+auto.master
```

**/etc/auto.cifs**

```
mntpoint   -fstype=cifs,username=winuser,password=winpass,file_mode=0666,dir_mode=0777   ://winpc/share
```

When you restart the `autofs` service, you'll have a new directory, `/cifs`.  You don't have to create it.  The `autofs` creates it, or destroys and then creates if already existing.  (So don't try to make your autofs root `/media` in your `auto.master` file).

Normally, when you `ls /cifs`, it would appear empty.  Navigating to `/cifs/mntpoint` would trigger the automount and make the missing mount appear.  However, the `--ghost` option makes the [mountpoints stay visible](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17094/automounter-browsing-with-nautilus), even when not mounted.

---

Alternatively, you could have this as the contents of **/etc/auto.cifs**:

```
*   -fstype=cifs,username=winuser,password=winpass,file_mode=0666,dir_mode=0777   ://winpc/&
```

This wildcard notation makes every share from `winpc` automountable by navigating to `/cifs/sharename` without having to define each share explicitly in `auto.cifs`.  This gives you the flexibility of creating and destroying shares on your Windows machine at will without having to change anything on your Linux box.

It makes the `--ghost` option useless, though, so `ls /cifs` would still appear empty when the cifs mounts haven't been triggered.  You'd either have to remember the share names or create symlinks with

```
ln -s /cifs/sharename ~/sharename
```

or similar.

---

Notice that in both examples of **auto.cifs** the `file_mode` and `dir_mode` options.  Those are the permissions applied to files and folders of cifs-mounted resources.  As they are, they grant read+write permission to everyone.  If you wish to dial in the security a little, then:

- create a group called "net" on your workstation: `groupadd net`
- add accounts to that group: `usermod -a -G net username`
- in **auto.cifs** add `uid=root,gid=net`
- in **auto.cifs** change `file_mode=0660,dir_mode=0770`

Also, if you're going to be storing your network share username and password in **auto.cifs** don't forget to `chmod 600 /etc/auto.cifs` to prevent non-root from reading it.

Answer (score 0):

To mount from Ubuntu 12.10 you need the cifs-utils package.

Then with root permissions:

> mount.cifs //hostname/UbuntuTest /mnt/remote -o username=smbuser

You can also mount via fstab (and I recommend using a credentials file containing the username and password):

> //hostname/UbuntuTest    /mnt/remote  cifs   credentials=/home/smbuser/credentials  0 0

Of course "smbuser" must be a valid active Windows account.